# MariabDB synchronous UPDATE query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, mariadb, synchronous

I'm working with PHP and MariaDB and I run into a problem.

I update a value to multiple rows, and then SELECT there rows to make a new calculation the data for another task.

The problem here that I get the wrong number. I guess that the MariaDB has not finished the UPDATE query, but it return the finished flag to PHP and then the PHP proceeds the SELECT query. [I just guess]

I open to any idea. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Thank you for sharing

This is my code

```
$modelAdminOrderBidSys = $this->load->model('Admin\Order\BidSys');

$acceptedItem = typeCast($modelAdminOrderBidSys->getItem($cartItemId));

if (!$acceptedItem) {
    return array(
        'result' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Cannot find item #' . $cartItemId
    );
}

$acceptedItem['lastOffer'] = $acceptedItem['offer'];
$acceptedItem['accepted'] = 1;
$acceptedItem['isBot'] = 0;

$modelAdminOrderBidSys->updateItem($cartItemId, array2object($acceptedItem));

$cartItems = typeCast($modelAdminOrderBidSys->getItems($acceptedItem['cartId']));

$accepted = 1;
$total = 0;
$offer = 0;
$lastOffer = 0;

foreach($cartItems as $cartItem) {
    if ((int)$cartItem['accepted'] < 1) {
        $accepted = 0;
    }

    $total += (float)$cartItem['total'];
    $offer += (float)$cartItem['offer'];
    $lastOffer += (float)$cartItem['lastOffer'];
}

$postField = new \stdClass();
$postField->accepted = $accepted;
$postField->total = $total;
$postField->offer = $offer;
$postField->lastOffer = $lastOffer;

$modelAdminOrderBidSys->updateCart($acceptedItem['cartId'], $postField);
```

Comment: Please share the code you are running. I'm unclear what the `finished flag` is, is that the show of affected rows?

Comment: Sorry for my unclear text. I mean that the MariaDB responds something to PHP so PHP doesn't need to wait and can continue to proceed the next code.

I update will update the code to my question shortly, please wait for a min.

Comment: Are there multiple scripts or only one php script? If there is only one, and it is the code in your question, you cannot run into concurrency issues, unless you are using some specific libraries like pthreads or parallel, but it is not in the code you are showing.
 
I think there is a `continue;` missing in your `if ((int)$cartItem['accepted'] < 1) {` : even if the cart item is not accepted, you still add it. But there are many things missing in your question, like your data model, or an example of what is happening and what you are expecting: what is the wrong number, and why ?

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL for the entire transaction.

Comment: @hsibboni I think you are right. This is an issue if it's submitted by multiple peoples at the same time. I will correct it now. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your SELECT transaction starts before the UPDATE has committed. Try changing the transaction_isolation (in config) / tx_isolation (at runtime with SET GLOBAL) to READ-COMMITTED. Default is REPEATABLE-READ.

Comment: You are right. I will try your solution. Thank you so much!